# function pointer and virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I guess my question should be silly but it is true that I have never seen a function pointer that is declared as virtual. Is there a reason for this?

Edit:

I should have said: Is it possible that the function it points to is specified as virtual?

Comment: I edit, please read and help me

Comment: Still not making sense to me. But the answer is that it's illegal to declare a function pointer as virtual. Even if the member function pointed to is virtual. Just tested this and got the error message "'virtual' not permitted on data declarations" which is a pretty good error message I think.

Comment: Please read other posts and comments. :-)

Comment: Right, got it now. I think I did answer your question in my original post, but Andrey gave a much more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, yes (and no).

Ordinary function pointers cannot point to non-static member functions. They can only point to standalone functions, which is why for ordinary function pointers the matter of function virtuality does not even come into the picture.

In order to point to member functions in C++ you need a pointer of special kind: one that has pointer-to-member-function type. A pointer of this type can point to non-virtual member functions as well and to virtual member functions. There are no special steps to take if you want to point to virtual member function. For example

```
struct B { 
  virtual void foo() {} 
  void bar() {} 
};

...
B b;
void (B::*pfunc)(); // declare a pointer to a member function

pfunc = &B::foo; // make it point to `B::foo`
(b.*pfunc)(); // calls `B::foo` for object `b`

pfunc = &B::bar; // make it point to `B::bar`
(b.*pfunc)(); // calls `B::bar` for object `b`
```

However, when you make such pointer to point to a virtual member function, you have to keep in mind that it is does not really get tied to a specific version of that function in the class hierarchy. The decision about the specific function to call is made at the point of the call. For example

```
// given the above `B`
struct D : B { 
  virtual void foo() {} 
};

...
void (B::*pfoo)(); // declare a pointer to a member function
pfoo = &B::foo; // and make it point to `B::foo`
```

In the above example we made out pointer `pfoo` to point to `B::foo`. Or did we? In reality  the pointer is not hard-linked to `B::foo` specifically. These two calls

```
B b;
D d;

(b.*pfoo)();
(d.*pfoo)();
```

will call two different functions. The first one will call `B::foo` for object `b`, while the second one will call `D::foo` for object `d`, even though we used the same pointer value in both cases. This makes sense actually in many applications.

Yet, in some low-level situation it would be useful to have a pointer that is hard-tied to a specific version of virtual function. I.e. it would be nice to have a pointer that would call `B::foo` for `B` subobject of object `d` when we do

```
(d.*pfoo)();
```

To achieve that we need to be able to specify whether we want to bind it early (at the point of initialization) or late (at the point of the call). Unfortunately, C++ language provides no such functionality.

Comment: Thank you, although I can't grasp all of what you actually tell me, I would like to accept your helpful reply as a solution. :-D

Answer (score 2):

A Function pointer is just a pointer to the function. It just stores address of an function just like any pointer to a `type` stores address of an type.

keyword `virtual` is used to implement polymorphic behavior(between functions of base class and derived class)through dynamic dispatch.

Given the above two are distinctly different and the idea of a function pointer to be virtual makes no sense at all.

***whether the function it points to is specified as virtual ?***
As I mentioned before an function pointer just stores address of an function. It is just an `type`. For eg:

```
int *i = NULL;
void doSomething();
typedef void(*ptr)() = NULL;
ptr = &doSomething();
```

In above example:
`i` is a type of `int *`. Similarly,
`ptr` is a type which can store address of an function which takes no parameter and returns no parameter.

So Yes, fundamentally, you can make the function to which a function pointer points as virtual, just like you would make any function virtual by declaring the particular function as virtual in the class.

The function pointer being a type can point to any function with that prototype, while declaring a function as virtual means having dynamic dispatch enabled on a *particular* function,  as you see both are not the same.

Comment: @What to eat tonight: Updated the answer to answer your Query

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I deleted it anyway. I am eating right now, please stay online waiting for my next question after i finishing my meal. I hope you can offer some useful help.

Answer (score 1):

Virtuality is a property of member functions. If you have a pointer to a virtual member function then a virtual call will be made automatically. Regular functions can't be virtual, so a virtual function pointer makes no sense. In either case there's no point making a function pointer virtual as its the function being pointed to that counts.